# How to make items in GridView (Flutter) resize automatically to fit the screen

Tags: android, flutter, gridview

I have following code. The items are added, but I want their size to be automatically calculated, so that all of them are fitting the screen.

```
GridView.count(
   // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
    crossAxisSpacing: 16,
    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
    childAspectRatio: 2/3,
      //maxCrossAxisExtent: width / 3
    crossAxisCount: itemsInRow(),
    children: _items.map((item) {
      return Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red
          ),
        ),
      );
      // return CardWidget(
      //   item: item,
      //   onTap: () {
      //     onCardTapped(item);
      //   },
      // );
    }).toList(),
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row and with `flex` or `LayoutBuilder` to calculate the size, while the question is about calculation I am using LayoutBuilder for this.

```dart
class FW extends StatelessWidget {
  const FW({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int cols = 2;
    int rows = 4;
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (_, constraints) {
          final boxSize =
              Size(constraints.maxWidth / cols, constraints.maxHeight / rows);
          return Column(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                Row(
                  children: [
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                      ColoredBox(
                        color: i + j < Colors.primaries.length
                            ? Colors.primaries[i + j]
                            : Colors.green, // if you
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: boxSize.width,//if you have padding on top level, minimize it 
                          height: boxSize.height,
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```